# cmd line in 14.04 to disable non free software

Tags: 14.04

I'm new to ubuntu,can you give me the cmd line to disable(delete) all multiverse(non-free) items from the software center, and the synaptic manager. thx dewitt

Comment: do you need a terminal command or are gui instructions fine?

Answer (score 0):

In Gnu/Linux:

```
Windows cmd-line = Terminal
```

To open a terminal press **(Ctrl+Alt+T)**

To disable all multiverse, non-free software:

Run it

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file, comment out to disable prefixing # these lines:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
```

So that they are well:

```
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
#deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
```

To remove, delete the lines.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.